# How to use CSS in LWUIT framework?

Tags: java, css, java-me, lwuit

I need to use css in LWUIT components. Is it possible? If its possible means tell me how we can use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can't add  the CSS for all LWUIT components. Only HTML components allows CSS in LWUIT. For more info see this [link](http://lwuit.blogspot.com/2010/05/css-support-in-lwuits-html-component.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can add the complete html in html component. The CSS needs to be there in html file. After setting the body text in html component lwuit renders some of the style sheets which it supports.